# how to use php in_array function with multiple array

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$name = array
  (
  array("b1",41),
  array("b2",43),
  array("b3",45),
  array("b4",47)
  );
```

I want to check if 43 is in array without using "b2"
My code:

```
if(in_array(array("b2", 43), $name)) { echo '1'; }
```

this code work fine but I want to check array without using "b2".
like this:

```
if(in_array(array(NULL, 43), $name)) { echo '1'; }
if(in_array(array(43), $name)) { echo '1'; }
```

thanks for any help

Comment: None of these helped you???

Answer (score 0):

Check that 43 is in the array but "b2" is not.

```
foreach ($name as $arr) {
    if (in_array(43, $arr) && !in_array("b2", $arr)) {
        echo '1';
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to check 43 is or not in array without using b2

Comment: @saitebisdamzadeba I'm not sure I understand, this is checking that the array has 43 but doesn't have b2. If that's NOT what you're looking for, then I think you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to flatten the array into a single dimension by merging the inner arrays:

```
if(in_array(43, call_user_func_array('array_merge', $name))) { echo 1; }
```

It doesn't actually modify the array, but it checks the flattened result that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => b1
    [1] => 41
    [2] => b2
    [3] => 43
    [4] => b3
    [5] => 45
    [6] => b4
    [7] => 47
)
```

You could also filter the array and check it:

```
if(array_filter($name, function($v) { return in_array(43, $v); })) { echo 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($name as $value) {

   if (in_array(43, $value)) {
    echo "1";
    break;
   }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a `break` so you don't check the entire array once found.

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_int(array_search(43, array_column($name, 1)))) {echo 1;}
```

Make sure your array structure for `$name` remain same as you shown here

Comment: I love `array_column()` but requires PHP >= 5.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array_reduce($name, function ($is, $n) { return $is || $n[1] == 43; })) {
    echo 'yes';
}
```

As a reusable function:

```
function is_in_array_key(array $array, $key, $value) {
    return array_reduce($array, function ($is, $i) use ($key, $value) {
        return $is || $i[$key] == $value;
    });
}

if (is_in_array_key($name, 1, 43)) {
    echo 'yes';
}
```